# How to know if sub directory exist in c++?

Tags: c++, filesystems

I want to stack directory until directory hits max-depth.
Therefore, I tried to use fs::filesystem.
At first, I approach by depth() like

```
 for (auto itr = fs::recursive_directory_iterator(fs::current_path()/path); itr != fs::recursive_directory_iterator(); itr++)
        {
           
             (itr.depth() == ???) 
                
            }
```

But Since I don't know max-depth. I failed.
how can I know if directory has sub-directory or not?

Comment: I've had directories that are nested thousands deep, on Unix.  I've had directories nested a thousand deep, on Windows.  Is *max-depth* your limitation, or are you interested in your platform's limitation?

Comment: @Eljay My limitation. Thanks.

Comment: Once you've hit your limit, then [`disable_recursion_pending`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator/disable_recursion_pending).

Comment: @Eljay But how can I know whether i hit my limit or not?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator/depth?

Comment: This sounds like an [xy-problem](https://xyproblem.info/).  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @G.M. I want to traverse directory by 'post-order' using `std::filesystem`. Since `recursive_directory_iterator`  exists, I thought If I utilize vector(or stack), I can easily implement. But I don't know how to handle max-depth directory.

Comment: Do you want to know the current directory's max-depth? Try a two pass approach.

Comment: @seccpur Yes I want to know current directory's max depth.

Comment: @justwanttoknoweverything "*how can I know if directory has sub-directory or not?*" and "*I want to know current directory's max depth*" are two completely different and unrelated questions. To answer the former, see [How can I know if directory have children directories in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72417186/65863)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this snippet to find max-depth in the current directory:

```
    int max_depth = 0;
    // use as first pass    
    for(auto itr = filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(filesystem::current_path()); itr != filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(); itr++)
    {
        if (is_directory(itr->path())) {
            if (itr.depth() > max_depth) max_depth = itr.depth();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Be careful, because `is_directory()` is true for `"."` and `".."` entries