# How can I know if directory have children directories in c++?

Tags: c++, filesystems

I want to check if directory have a child directory.
I thought I can find by ++operator But it didn't work.

```
 for (auto itr = fs::recursive_directory_iterator(fs::current_path() / path); itr != fs::recursive_directory_iterator(); itr++)
            {                  
                if (!(* itr++).exists())
                    cout <<*itr << endl;
                   
            }
```

any tips?

Comment: can you please clarify "it didnt work"?

Comment: @Borgleader its output was different from what i expect. I have no idea why such a result came about.

Comment: Try : if (is_directory(itr->path()))

Comment: What is the output? What did you expect? This code unconditionally increments the iterator inside the loop before the output, so perhaps that is the issue? Can you explain the purpose of that code? Do you expect the iteration to produce entries that do not exist? Why?

Comment: @seccpur or, `if (itr->is_directory())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `(recursive_)directory_iterator` gives you access to a list of child items, both files and directories. It is up to you to differentiate between files and directories, eg:

```
bool has_child_directory(const fs::path &dir)
{
    for (auto itr = fs::directory_iterator(dir); itr != fs::directory_iterator(); ++itr)
    {                  
        if (itr->is_directory())
        {
            string s = itr->path().string();
            if ((s != ".") && (s != ".."))
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```